# Symfony service. How to pass arguments in registration?

Tags: symfony

In my Symfony project I have manager, in which I injected two interfaces.

```
class ActionLogsManager
{
    private $entityManager;
    private $container;
    private $token;

 public function __construct(EntityManager $manager, ContainerInterface 
    $container, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $manager;
        $this->container = $container;
        $this->token = $token;
    }
}
```

I want to register this manager in services.yml, but i dont know how to pass these interfaces as parameters (dont know the correct syntax for this)

```
services:
     managers.action_log_manager:
            class: MyBundle\Managers\ActionLogsManager
            arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', ?, ?]
```

Comment: it s a abd idea to inject all the container

Comment: In this case, is there another way to use container in manager?

Comment: never pass the container, only what you need. container is too big

Comment: Actually you don't inject interfaces but services that implement interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TokenStorageInterface instead of TokenInterface. Aliases for those services are `@service_container` and `@security.token_storage`.

Your services.yml will look as follows:

```
services:
     managers.action_log_manager:
            class: MyBundle\Managers\ActionLogsManager
            arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager', '@service_container', '@security.token_storage']
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer)

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple. You can use the console command to find it.

```
  bin/console debug:container
```

On the left column - Service ID, on the right - Class name.
As example look at the [screenshot](http://take.ms/5KTLqz)